# QVariant and QObject relation - class Hierarchy?

Tags: c++, qt

I was going over the class hierarchy of Qt and read that not all objects inherit from QObject for example QString. I wanted to know where does QVariant stand in the class hierarchy. I could not find a class hierarchy diagram that could explain this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Qt library tries to mimic (and possibly extend) the standard and boost libraries. For example `QString` is similar to `std::string`, `QVector` to `std::vector` and `QVariant` is in some way related to `boost::variant`. These kind of objects are not part of the main class hierarchy that starts with `QObject`, but are, instead, part of the [QtCore](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtcore.html) module.

Answer (score 1):

QVariant is not a QObject and does not inherit from any other Qt type (has no hierarchy).